# Слишком медленно работает PHP-скрипт приёма и сохранения изображения

Tags: php, mysql, изображения, orm

Здравствуйте. Это скрипт обновления аватара пользователя. Приём фотографии, уменьшение размера, создание папки, сохранение в ней под определённым названием. Также тут сразу идёт формирование поста для стены, о том, что пользователь обновил аватар. Всё это пихается в базу. И изображение сохраняется ещё и в папку с постами этого пользователя. Срабатывает долго... Очень хотелось бы сделать лучше. Буду рад любому совету или критике.

```
    else if($user->step == 5 AND $post = $this->request->post('add_avatar'))
        {
            if($_FILES['avatar']['name'] !== "") 
            {
                $last_post = ORM::factory('Post')
                    ->limit(1)
                    ->order_by('id', 'DESC')
                    ->find();

                $last_post  =  $last_post->id;
                $last_post++;

                $path       = 'public/images/user/'.$user->id.'/';
                $dir        = 'public/images/post/'.$user->id;
                $post       = 'public/images/post/'.$user->id.'/'.$last_post.'/';

                if (file_exists($dir))
                {
                    if (file_exists($dir.'/'.$last_post))
                    {
                        function dirDel ($dir) 
                        {  
                            $d=opendir($dir);  
                            while(($entry=readdir($d))!==false) 
                            { 
                                if ($entry != "." && $entry != "..") 
                                { 
                                    if (is_dir($dir."/".$entry)) 
                                    {  
                                        dirDel($dir."/".$entry);  
                                    } 
                                    else 
                                    {  
                                        unlink ($dir."/".$entry);  
                                    } 
                                } 
                            } 
                            closedir($d);  
                            rmdir ($dir);  
                        } 

                        dirDel($dir.'/'.$last_post);
                        mkdir($post, 0700);
                    }
                    else 
                    {
                        mkdir($post, 0700);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    mkdir($dir, 0700);
                    mkdir($post, 0700);
                }

                if($user->avatar == 1)
                    {
                        unlink($path.'avatar.jpg');
                    }

                    $size       = 1000;
                    $src        = imagecreatefromjpeg($_FILES['avatar']['tmp_name']);
                    $w_src      = imagesx($src); 
                    $h_src      = imagesy($src);
                    $w          = $size;

                    if($w_src >= $w)
                    {
                        $ratio  = $w_src/$w;
                        $w_dest = round($w_src/$ratio);
                        $h_dest = round($h_src/$ratio);
                        $dest   = imagecreatetruecolor($w_dest, $h_dest);

                        imagecopyresampled($dest, $src, 0, 0, 0, 0, $w_dest, $h_dest, $w_src, $h_src);
                        imagejpeg($dest, $path.'avatar.jpg');
                        imagejpeg($dest, $post.'main.jpg');
                        imagedestroy($dest);

                        $model = ORM::factory('Post'); 
                        $model->values(array( 
                            'post_id' => $last_post, 
                            'user_id' => $this->user->id, 
                            'text' => 'обновил фотографию на странице', 
                            'img' => '1'
                        ));

                        if(!$model->save())
                        {
                            $errors = 'Не удалось добавить запись. Попробуйте снова.';
                        }

                        $count = ORM::factory('Profile')
                            ->where('user_id', '=', $user->id)
                            ->find();
                        $count_post = $count->count_post;
                        $count_post++;

                        $data = array('count_post' => $count_post);

                        ORM::factory('Profile', $count->id)
                            ->values($data)
                            ->save();                            
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $dest   = imagecreatetruecolor($w_src, $h_src);

                        imagecopyresampled($dest, $src, 0, 0, 0, 0, $w_src, $h_src, $w_src, $h_src);
                        imagejpeg($dest, $path.'avatar.jpg');
                        imagejpeg($dest, $post.'main.jpg');
                        imagedestroy($dest);

                        $model = ORM::factory('Post'); 
                        $model->values(array( 
                            'post_id' => $last_post, 
                            'user_id' => $this->user->id, 
                            'text' => 'обновил фотографию на странице', 
                            'img' => '1'
                        ));

                        if(!$model->save())
                        {
                            $errors = 'Не удалось добавить запись. Попробуйте снова.';
                        }

                        $count = ORM::factory('Profile')
                            ->where('user_id', '=', $user->id)
                            ->find();
                        $count_post = $count->count_post;
                        $count_post++;

                        $data = array('count_post' => $count_post);

                        ORM::factory('Profile', $count->id)
                            ->values($data)
                            ->save(); 
                    }

                    imagedestroy($src);

                    $this->redirect("/id".$user->id);
                }
                else
                {
                    $errors ='Не была загружена картинка';
                }

        }
```

Comment: Вставляешь на страницу прогресс-бар и готово! Оно не тормозит, оно обрабатывает :)

Comment: @Vasily Koshelev хороший вариант, но хотелось бы всё-таки по-другому решать проблемы :)

Comment: "Срабатывает долго" - понятие растяжимое. Зависит от многих факторов, таких как скорость интернета, скорость работы либы, которая уменьшает размер.
Вы тестировали в идеальных условиях - все действия производили на одном сервере?

Comment: @VasilyKoshelev на локальном и на хостинге. Просто у меня такие мысли, что я делаю слишком много действий, Может можно как-то сократить код или запросы к БД? А может я вообще какие-то функции не так использую, как необходимо... Я только учу PHP, поэтому вот.

Comment: @VasilyKoshelev И ещё, этот код я использую и при обновлении обложки профиля пользователя. Просто такой же кусок кода, только при условии, что была отправлена другая форма. Это всё в одном контроллере. Может ли быть это замедление из-за этих условий? Вообще думал этот кусок в отдельную функцию вынести... но не знаю, как это лучше сделать

Comment: Ну то есть ты считаешь, что дело в количестве функций? А при готовке обеда, к которому надо подать 10 яблок и казан плова, время на готовку зависит от количества яблок - если следовать твоей логике?

Comment: Не, ну попробуйте найти узкое место.
В браузере же есть средства отладки. Попробуйте вынести в отдельную страничку загрузку изображения и сравните время выполнения скрипта внутри приложения и отдельно. Если будет расхождение большое - дело в приложении, если не будет расхождения - все в порядке.
Вроде как, по логике, у тебя все нормально - функции идут одна за другой, запись в бд в конце.

Comment: @Ипатьев я просто поинтересовался. Если не можешь узнать причину - необходимо исследовать все варианты. Тем более, я надеялся, что знающие люди мне помогут докопаться до истины.

Comment: @VasilyKoshelev спасибо огромное!

Comment: Ну то есть ты считаешь вариант с пловом логичным. Неважно, сколько готовится каждое блюдо, важно сколько их всего. Ну ок, вопросов нет.

Comment: @Ипатьев скажем так. По логике, 5 литров плова готовятся быстрее, чем 10 литров. А если печка одна, то два блюда готовятся дольше, чем одно, потому что одновременно их нельзя готовить.

Comment: Ну вот в этом и состоит твоя проблема - ты не можешь понять, чем плов отличается от яблока и что обед состоит не из одного только плова.

Comment: @Ипатьев я понимаю, к чему вы клоните. Функции сами по себе, если их не вызывать, не дают нагрузку на сервер, и срабатывают лишь в случае вызова. То есть, если я укажу 100 функций, но применю всего одну, то только она и вызовет нагрузку. Так?

Comment: Вообще-то так далеко моя аналогия не заходила. И про функции, которые не вообще не исполняются, я ничего не писал - мне не приходило в голову, что их тоже можно умудриться посчитать. Мой намек был про то, что разные функции имеют разное время выполнения.

Comment: @Ипатьев Ладно) Спасибо вам.